# Wrapping a binary data file to self-convert to CSV?

Tags: bash, gcc, binary-data

I'm writing custom firmware for a SparkFun Logomatic V2 that records binary data to a file on a 2GB micro-SD card.  The data file size will range from 100 MB to 1 GB.

The format of the binary data is in flux as the board's firmware evolves (it will actually be dynamically reconfigurable at run-time).  Rather than create and maintain a separate decoder/converter program for each version of firmware/configuration, I'd much rather make the data files self-converting to CSV format by starting the data file with a Bash script that is written to the data file before data recording starts.

I know how to create a Here Document, but I suspect Bash would be unable to quickly parse and convert a gigabyte of binary data, so I'd like to make the process run much faster by having the script first compile some C code (assume GCC is present and in the path), then run the resulting program, passing the binary data to stdin.

To make the problem more concrete, assume the firmware will create binary data consisting of 4 16-bit integer values: A timestamp (unsigned) followed by 3 accelerometer axes (signed).  There is no separator between records (mainly because I'm saturating the SPI interface to the uSD card).

So, I think I need a script with TWO here documents: One for the C code (parameterized by expanded Bash variables), and another for the binary data.  Here's where I am so far:

```
#! env bash
# Produced by firmware version 0.0.0.0.0.1 alpha
# Configuration for this data run:
header_string = "Time, X, Y, Z"
column_count = 4
# Create the converter executable
# Use "<<-" to permit code to be indented for readability.
# Allow variable expansion/substitution.
gcc -xc /tmp/convertit - <<-THE_C_CODE
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main (int argc, char **argv) {
        // Write ${header_string} to stdout
        while (1) {
            // Read $(column_count} shorts from stdin
            // Break if EOF
            // Write $(column_count} comma-delimited values to stdout
        }
        // Close stdout
        return 0;
    }
THE_C_CODE
# Pass the binary data to the converter
# Hard-quote the Here tag to prevent subsequent expansion/substitution
/tmp/convertit >./$1.csv <<'THE_BINARY_DATA'
...
... hundreds of megabytes of semi-random data ...
...
THE_BINARY_DATA
rm /tmp/convertit
exit 0
```

Does that look about right?  I don't yet have a real data file to test this with, but I wanted to verify the idea before going much further.

Will Bash complain if the closing lines are missing? This may happen if data capture terminates unexpectedly due to a shock knocking loose the battery or uSD card.  Or if the firmware borks.

Is there a faster or better method I should consider?  For example, I wonder if Bash will be too slow to copy the binary data as fast as the C program can consume it: Should the C program open the data file directly?

TIA,

-BobC

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at [makeself](http://megastep.org/makeself/). It allows you to change any .tar.gz archive into a self-extracting file which is platform independent (something like a shell script that contains a here document). This will allow you to easily distribute your data and decoder. It also allows you to configure a script contained within the archive to be run when the container script is run. This way you can use makeself for packaging and inside the archive you can put your data files and decoder written in C or bash or whatever language you find suitable.

While it is possible to decode binary data using shell tools (e.g. using `od`), it's very cumbersome and ineffective. I'd recommend using either a C program or perl which is also likely to be found on almost any machine (check [this page](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/learn/ch16_02.htm)).